# how to bind the value from the event fired in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and vue.js

I have a template

```
<div name="alpha"></div>
<div name="bravo"></div>
<div name="charlie"></div>
```

I need to bind the value from the event on the div.

```
function UpdateProgress($target, $value)
{
   $this->target =$target;
   $this->value = $value;
}
```

In tinker after triggering the event

```
>>> event(new UpdateProgress('alpha', 99));
>>> event(new UpdateProgress('alpha', 100));
>>> event(new UpdateProgress('charlie', 456));
```

I could not get the value  appended to the corresponding div's associated..Could anyone please help to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Event return void. Do you expect some other kind of return type in event class?

Comment: I want the value , for ex if a div containing the name alpha then value should be appended to that particular div with the 99 value and the same with the other div's too..How could I do that?Could you please help me?

Comment: "In tinker after triggering the event I could not get the value" You are not supposed to get value from an event. You are triggering event and that's it. An event in Laravel returns void - meaning no return. If you want to get value from DIV you should use JavaScript instead. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Yes you got it.. I am new to javascript ..Could you please help? ,  how to include the script (where to include as well)? .. Thanks a lot for your support